# Pydub AudioSegment export has no sound

Tags: python-3.x, pydub

I have this simple code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

audio = AudioSegment.from_wav("recordings/source.wav")
audio.export("recordings/export.wav", format="wav")
```

The `source.wav` is a 5-second recording. The code generates the `export.wav`, but the file is completely empty. It's a 0s wav file.

There is nothing else to my code, only the part that I pasted here. My goal is to eventually extract a chunk of an audio file, but it's already not working at this stage.

I tried to run the debugging suggested on the [Read.me](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)

```
import logging

l = logging.getLogger("pydub.converter")
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

But I am not getting any errors. The script executes itself without issue.
I also tried `AudioSegment.from_file`, without success.

What am I missing?

I am using `pydub 0.25.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't fix it, but using an `.mp3` file instead of a `.wav` worked.